# How do I write this SQL query with 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery

There is a table called `AssociateAuditorMap` with 3 columns `AssociateID`, `AuditorID` and  `IsActive` (bool).

Each `AssociateID` will have only one `AuditorID` mapped to it.One auditor may have many associates mapped to them.

There is a 2nd table called `UserMaster` with 2 columns `UserID` and `RoleID`.

Now given that `Auditors` are in the `UserMaster` with `RoledID=2`, what is the query to find 
auditors who do not have any associates mapped to them in the `AssociateAuditorMap` table?

That is, find `Auditors` who do not have any rows in the `AssociateAuditorMap` table.

Comment: Google the SQL `except` operator in SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: I associate them, because the Auditor of AssociateAuditorMap is also a User with RoleID=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT 
    u.UserID, u.RoleID
FROM 
    dbo.UserMaster u
WHERE
    u.RoleId = 2 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.AssociateAuditorMap aam 
                    WHERE aam.AuditorID = u.UserID)
```

This would list all rows from `UserMaster` with a `RoleID = 2` (auditors) that have no entry in the `AssociateAuditorMap` table with that `AuditorID`

Comment: Would not it be more efficient if a join and compare null?

Comment: Maybe - maybe not - depends on too many factors (like number of rows, indexes present etc.). The `NOT EXISTS` approach typically is quite efficient, however